# Error with blob image

Tags: php, blob

I am using the following code to crop an image and getting the following error.

**ERROR**

> **Warning**:  imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a
>   recognized format in
>   **C:\MAMP\htdocs\mike\dist\functions\crop.php** on line
>   **20**
>  
>  **Warning**:  imagecopyresampled() expects
>   exactly 10 parameters, 8 given in
>   **C:\MAMP\htdocs\mike\dist\functions\crop.php** on line
>   **21**
>  
>  **Warning**:  imagestring() expects exactly
>   6 parameters, 2 given in
>   **C:\MAMP\htdocs\mike\dist\functions\crop.php** on line
>   **22**

**NOTE**

`$img_name` is a blob

for example: `blob:http%3A//localhost/c1d90080-4603-4aa4-a618-555a70f840dd`

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
  $img_name = $_POST['imgname']; //this is an blob
  $cropx = $_POST['crop_X'];
  $cropy = $_POST['crop_y'];
  $cropw = $_POST['cropw'];
  $croph = $_POST['croph'];

  $dst_X = 0;
  $dst_Y = 0;
  $src_X = $cropx;
  $src_Y = $cropy;
  $dst_w = $cropw;
  $dst_h = $croph;
  $src_w = $src_X + $dst_w;
  $src_w = $src_Y + $dst_h;

  $dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
  $src_image = imagecreatefromstring($img_name);
  imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, 
                     $dst_X, $dst_Y, 
                     $src_X, $src_Y, 
                     $dst_w, $dst_h
                    );
  imagestring($dst_image, "/dist/cropped.png");
```

Comment: Did you find this answer @saqib ?

Answer (score 0):

BLOBs are typically binary data of the image from than a URL string to a file does the URL point directly to the location of the image as you may need to parse the URL from the string and use `file_get_contents($url)` before pushing this to `imagecreatefromstring`

for example:

```
$img_name = $_POST['imgname'];
$parts = explode(':', $img_name);
$img_string = file_get_contents($parts[1]);

imagecreatefromstring($img_string);
```

Comment: this is not working

in browser without 'blob:' file can't be open so its showing the following error
file_get_contents(http%3A//localhost/e2220d4e-c7a2-4096-a04c-b87741b5d591): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: can you try using file_get_contents with $img_name instead then?

Comment: imagecreatefromstring needs to have binary input so you need to read the raw data from the image from you are creating so you need to be able to access the image from where ever the script is running, do you know how you can access the file from within the server enviroment

Comment: Thanks for your time. it is hard to find it now i am trying something else.